# Set CreateFromMenu texts on CMFCMenuBar during CMDIFrameWndEx::OnCreate

Tags: c++, mfc

I have problem setting my texts in in the menu during the creation of the window:

```
OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
...
CMFCMenuBar    m_wndMenuBar;    
CMenu menu;    
menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU_ENGGB);
m_wndMenuBar.Create(this);
m_wndMenuBar.CreateFromMenu(menu.GetSafeHmenu(),TRUE,TRUE);
...
}
```

My problem is that the previous state is taken from the registry and I haven't found a way to change the language to the correct one during the creation of the window.

I found that if I dump the entry for the application in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\"MyApplication" I mange to get the default language for my application.

Is there some way that I can choose which text to use during the creation of the window?

All suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by overloding LoadState wich lodes the state from the registry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\"MyApplication"\Workspace\MFCToolBar-"id"

BOOL CVodiaMenuBar::LoadState( LPCTSTR lpszProfileName, int nIndex, UINT uiID)
{
    //CMFCMenuBar::LoadState(lpszProfileName, nIndex, uiID);
    return TRUE;
}
```

By not calling the parent my changes was kept after OnCreate.